# UniVerse - SQL LIST: View List of All Database Tables

Tags: sql, universe

I am trying to obtain a list of all the DB Tables that will give me visibility on what tables I may need to JOIN for running SQL scripts.

For example, in TCL when I run "LIST.DICT" it returns "Name of File:" for input. I then enter "PRODUCT" and it returns a list of all available fields.

However, Where can I get a list of all my available Tables or list of my options that I can enter after "Name of File:"?

Here is what I am trying to achieve. In the screen shot below, I would like to run a SQL script that gives me the latest Log File Activity, Date - Time - Description. I would like the script to return '8/13/14  08:40am BR: 3;BuyPkg'

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From TCL within the database account containing your database files, type:  LISTF

Sample output:
FILES in your vocabulary                      03:21:38pm  29 Jun 2015 Page  1

Filename........................... Pathname...................... Type Modulo

```
 File - Contains all logical device names
```

DICT &DEVICE&                       /u1/uv/D_&DEVICE&                 2      1 
DATA &DEVICE&                       /u1/uv/&DEVICE&                   2      3

```
 File - Used by MAKE.MAP.FILE
```

DICT &MAP&                          /u1/uv/D_&MAP&                    2      1 
DATA &MAP&                          /u1/uv/&MAP&                      6      7

```
 File - Contains all parts of Distributed Files
```

DICT &PARTFILES&                    /u1/uv/D_&PARTFILES&              2      1 
DATA &PARTFILES&                    /u1/uv/&PARTFILES&               18      7

DICT &PH&                           D_&PH&                            3      1 
DATA &PH&                           &PH&                              1

DICT &SAVEDLISTS&                   D_&SAVEDLISTS&                    3      1 
DATA &SAVEDLISTS&                   &SAVEDLISTS&                      1

```
 File - Used by uniVerse to access the current directory.
```

DICT &UFD&                          /u1/uv/D_UFD                      2      1 
DATA &UFD&                          .                                19      1

DICT &XML&                          D_&XML&                          18      3 
DATA &XML&                          &XML&                            19      1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, UniVerse has no Log File Activity Date and Time.

However, you can still obtain the table's modified/ accessed date from the file system however. 
To do this,

1. You need to have a subroutine accepting a path of the table to return a date or a time. 
   e.g. `SUBROUTINE GET.FILE.MOD.DATE(DAT.MOD, S.FILE.PATH)`

Inside the subroutine, you can use **EXECUTE** to run shell command like **istat** for getting these info on a unix e.g.
Please beware that for a dynamic file e.g. there are Data and Overflow parts under a directory. You should compare the dates obtained and return only the latest one.

2. Globally catalog the subroutine
3. Create an I-Desc in VOC, e.g. I.FILE.MOD.DATE in the field definition of this I-Desc: `SUBR("*GET.FILE.MOD.DATE",F2) and Conv Code as "D/MDY2"`
4. Create another I-Desc e.g. I.FILE.MOD.TIME

Finally, you can

```
LIST VOC I.FILE.MOD.DATE I.FILE.MOD.TIME DESC WITH TYPE LIKE "F..."
```

alternatively in SQL,

```
SELECT I.FILE.MOD.DATE, I.FILE.MOD.TIME, VOC.DESC FROM VOC WHERE TYPE LIKE "F%";
```